# In python 3, why can encoding declarations be written as a comment?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding

Section 2.1.3 of the Python Language Reference says:

> Comments are ignored by the syntax.

While I'm not entirely sure about this, I believe this means the Python Intepreter will ignore comments.

In contrast, section 2.1.4 says:

> If a comment in the first or second line of the Python script matches the regular expression coding[=:]\s*([-\w.]+), this comment is processed as an encoding declaration.

This also seems to be a statement of fact about the Python Interpreter: That it does not ignore a comment if it's in the first or second line of the script, as long as it matches the expression `coding[=:]\s*([-\w.]+)`

[Source](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations)

Don't these two statements about the interpreter contradict each other? What the hell is going on?

Comment: Simple. Section 2.1.4 is an exception to 2.1.3. You will find many similar rules and exceptions to those rules in Python docs, and in other software.

Comment: So the interpreter does not ignore a comment if it's in the first or second line of the Python script and if it matches the regular expression `coding[=:]\s*([-\w.]+)`. But why doesn't section 2.1.3 just say `Comments are usually ignored during the syntax unless <include all exceptions here>`? In my mind that's how you should write a language reference, otherwise you risk causing the reader to wonder if there are other exceptions hidden throughout the reference.

Comment: You can propose a pull request if you wish!

Comment: It is next to impossible to keep the documentation in a 100% consistent state for such a huge project. Unfortunately this is how Real Life™ works. See the list of currently known issues in the documentation [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue?@filter=status&@filter=components&components=4&status=1&@columns=id,activity,title,status&@sort=-activity). Feel free to submit a [bug report](https://docs.python.org/3/bugs.html#documentation-bugs) to improve it.

Comment: @Selcuk I'm not sure if you read the edit I made, but either way, do you know of any other exceptions to the rule about how comments are ignored by the syntax? I want to make sure that when I make that pull request, I get everything right.

Comment: I don't, but I'm not an authority on Python docs.

Comment: On Python sources, the env variables and the first lines are checked, to override the default encoding (checking predefined bytes strings). Without setting an encoding, you cannot find "the comment character" and so comments.

Answer (score 1):

You have valid points about the clarity of the documentation.

However, as with many other languages (HTML, XML, JSON pre-2017 standard*), the character encoding of a source file/document is determined prior to any language lexical or syntactical processing. So, it is correct to say, "Comments are ignored by the syntax." Because once the character encoding is determined, processing restarts and the syntactical processing ignores all comments.

In a sense, there are two languages: 1) for expressing the character encoding; 2) for expressing a Python script. The first one is designed so it is accepted by but has no meaning to the second.

---

- Subsequent standards for JSON reduce the set of allowable character encoding from UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-32BE to simply UTF-8.